# Finding a base from matrice subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

$U,W$ are sub-spaces of $M^\mathbb{R}_{2x2}$
$$U=Sp\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\  4 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\  3 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 11\\  7 & -2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
$$W=Sp\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 &5\\  5 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\  1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\  1 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

Find a base for $U \cap W$

I got a bit stuck on this question not sure on how to use *Gaussian elimination* in order to find the base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$M^\mathbb{R}_{2x2}$ is $\Bbb R^4$ written a little bit different (more precisely, each matrix $(a_{ij})$ can be "identified" with the vector $(a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22})$), apply Gaussian elimination to check whether the *vectors* that span $U$ (and $W$) are linearly independent or not.

---

Here's an idea about what to do next:

Try to establish $U$ as an equation, i.e., once you have the basis $\{(1,2,4,1),(0,3,1,-1)\}$ of $U$, reduce the matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0 & x \\ 2 & 3 & y\\ 4 & 1 & z \\ 1 & -1 & w\end{array}\right]$$

to find a condition on $(x,y,z,w)$ to be on $U$. Do the same for $W$ and then solve the system of equations you find from there. After that, find a basis for that solution set (Notice we could do this from the beginning without finding a basis for $U$ and $W$, however, this reduces the quantity of computations).

Comment: from what I understood I need to find $U$ and $W$ basis separately ? so I was trying to do what you said for $U$ and I used a matrice for as follows: those are the rows: (1,2,4,1), (1, -1, 3, 2), (1,11,7,-2) and I used row reduction and reached this matrix: (1,2,4,1), (0,1 1/3, -1/3),(0,0,0,0) does that mean that the base of $U$ are those 2 vectors (and to convert them to matrix ofcousre).

Comment: It's precisely that! (of course, $U$ and $W$ need separate procedures). (You have a typo on your comment, it's $(1,2,4,1)$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful

Comment: You're welcome Div. Glad it helped.

Comment: just another quick question if W is $(1,5,5,0), (0,1,1,1)$ so $U \cap W=\{0\}$ 
? I'm not sure I got this one right

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your answer...

Comment: after finding the basis of U which is $(1,2,4,1), (0,1, 1/3, -1/3)$ I also found the basis of W $(1,5,5,0),(0,1,1,1)$ but how do I find the basis of $U \cap W$ ?

Comment: I've edited my answer